# Is there a way to automate differencing of time series in R?

Tags: r, time-series

I would like to do some time series analysis. When, for example, I have a time series expressed as a single row of a data frame, I receive the following error when carrying out the augmented Dickey-Fuller test:
"Error in tseries::adf.test(B) : x is not a vector or univariate time series."
So I have made it into a vector:

```
library(urca)
B <- c(34,34,34,34,34,34,35,100,34,34,35,100,34)
B
plot(B)
tseries::adf.test(B)
```

But the time series must then be part of a data frame in order to apply differencing, otherwise I will get the error:

> "Error in apply(B, 1, f1) : dim(X) must have a positive length",

So, I have redefined `B` manually as follows:

```
A <- c(34)
C <- c(34)
D <- c(34)
E <- c(34)
F <- c(34)
G <- c(34)
H <- c(35)
I <- c(100)
J <- c(34)
K <- c(34)
L <- c(35)
M <- c(100)
N <- c(34)
B <- data.frame(A,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N)
B
f1 = function(x){return(diff(x))}
C <- (t(apply(B,1, f1)))
C <- data.frame(t(apply(B,1, f1)))
class(C)
```

R then tells me the class of C is a data frame. If I keep C in this format, I again obtain "Error in tseries::adf.test(C) : x is not a vector or univariate time series" when re-performing the D-F test. If I don't include "data.frame", it says the class of C is numeric and I obtain the following error when re-performing the D-F test: "Error in embed(y, k) : wrong embedding dimension".

So I manually rewrote the result as a vector again:

```
C <- c(0,0,0,0,0,1,65,-66,0,1,65,-66)
class(C)
C
plot(C)
tseries::adf.test(C)
```

Which all works fine, but is there a way to automate this so I don't have to keep converting from vector to data frame to vector again? I would like to keep everything as a data frame if possible.

Many thanks!

Comment: `apply(matrix(B, nrow = 1), 1, f1)`

Comment: To create the dataframe, `B<-data.frame(as.list(B))`. You don't have to do it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert `B` to a time.series object:

```
B_ts <- ts(B)
```

You can then specify the frequency, start and end of the time series, see `?ts` for more details.

If you want to take first order differences of `B` you can simply use `diff(B)`. The data does not have to be a dataframe for this